# Linux | Authorization management for users who should become root

Tags: linux, authorization, root

**Scenario 1**

Imagine, you have several Admins, all they have their own ser name like tom, john, adam. They all are able to be root. This means that everyone could be root at the same time and issue sensitive commands. Is there a way to determine afterwards who has logged in as root AND who has used which command as root? For example, Tom logged in as root and rebooted the server, or John logged in as root and restarted Tomcat, etc.

**Scenario 2**

Similar to scenario 1, with the difference that the admins do not have a personal user name, but use a shared user and then log in as root. In this case, is it possible to check afterwards who logged on with the shared username and what he did afterwards as root? Is this logged in the system (IP or other data)

__

Can you recommend a simple, lean authorization concept for root users, with which you can see who did what on the servers? Access to the server should remain largely simple, e.g. via mRemote.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I think could somehow work for :

#### Senario 1

You can always watch the content of `~/.bash_history` but the user can edit/remove the file.
Also if the user uses `su` and not `sudo`, you won't see anything

#### Senario 2

You can use the sshd logs to see who connected using what have been done here https://serverfault.com/questions/130482/how-to-check-sshd-log

Or in the `~/.bash_login` file you can log the `$SSH_CLIENT` into something (sent it with curls, echo it into a log file), but here also keep in mind that user can edit `~/.bash_login`